# RSpec Rails PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column <table>.<another_class_name>_type does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have three models associated the following way:

```
class A < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ownerships, as: :owner, inverse_of: :owner, foreign_key: :owner_id
  has_many :cs, through: :ownerships
```

Then:

```
class Ownership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'A', foreign_key: :owner_id, inverse_of: :ownerships
  belongs_to :c, inverse_of: :ownership
```

Last:

```
class C < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :ownership, inverse_of: :c
  has_one :owner, class_name: 'A', through: :ownership
```

**There is no polymorphic association between these classes**

The models run fine except when I try to test them with RSpec.
If I try to to print for instance the ownerships of A with `pp a.ownerships`, it will complain that:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
  PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column ownerships.owner_type does not exist
  LINE 1: ...wnerships" WHERE "ownerships"."owner_id" = $1 AND "ownership...
```

I simply do not get it...

Comment: Additional details:
- Rails 6.1
- Ruby 3.0
- RSpec-Rails 5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `as:` option is exclusively used to setup [polymorphic assocations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) which is why ActiveRecord is creating a query for an `owner_type` column. Its not needed here.

```
class A < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ownerships, 
    inverse_of: :owner,
    foreign_key: :owner_id
  has_many :cs, through: :ownerships
end
```

Comment: Perfect! This solved it.